# K&R Explanation of echo program is confusing, when debugging it using gdb. What's wrong?

Tags: c, linux, bash, gdb, kernighan-and-ritchie

As per K&R, his explanation of echo program: 
`echo hello world`
"By convention, argv[0] is the name by which the program was invoked, so argc is at least 1. If the argc is 1, there are no command-line arguments after the program name. In the example above, argc is 3, and argv[0], argv[1], and argv[2] are "echo", "hello", and "world" respectively. The first optional argument is argv[1] and the last is argv[argc-1]."

But, when debugging the program, using gdb, I can see the following:

```
(gdb) p argv[0]
$2 = 0x7efff85a "/home/pi/new/a.out"
(gdb) p argv[1]
$3 = 0x0
(gdb) p argv[2]
$4 = 0x7efff86d "LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc"...
(gdb) p *argv[0]
    $5 = 47 '/'
```

Ex 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    while (--argc>0)
        printf("%s%s",*++argv,(argc>1)?" ":"");
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

For the code example above, when compiling and executing as the below:

```
pi@readonly:~/new$ cc -g echo.c
pi@readonly:~/new$ a.out hello world
hello world
```

Debug using gdb:

Snippet 1:

```
(gdb) p &*argv
$11 = (char **) 0x7efff744
(gdb) p &**argv
$12 = 0x7efff85a "/home/pi/new/a.out"
(gdb) p argv
$13 = (char **) 0x7efff744
(gdb) p &argv
$14 = (char ***) 0x7efff5e0
(gdb) p &argv[0]
$15 = (char **) 0x7efff744
(gdb) p argv[0]
$16 = 0x7efff85a "/home/pi/new/a.out"
```

Snippet 2:

```
(gdb) p argv[3]
$22 = 0x7efffe5a "_=/usr/bin/gdb"
(gdb) p argv[4]
$23 = 0x7efffe69 "LANG=en_GB.UTF-8"
(gdb) p &argv[3]
$24 = (char **) 0x7efff754
```

Questions:

• Snippet 1:

1. Am I understand it correctly, that `0x7efff85a` is the hexadecimal value of the string `"/home/pi/new/a.out"`? If yes, how it has been obtained? In other words, has it been obtained by using, for instance, `atoi()` function?

• Snippet 3:

2. Am I understand it correctly, that, `_=/usr/bin/gdb` is converted into `0x7efffe5a`?
3. Also, there is some predefined values being set to the array argv, because, in case, nothing has been input, it is there. Where can I read about this predefined values? Is it implementation-defined? For instance, on windows, using Eclipse, or other IDEs, would it give different but, predefined values set as well for argv[] array?

Comment: No, they are addresses (pointers). Look at the type you're trying to print.

Comment: You need to use the `set args` command within GDB to set the program's command-line arguments.

Comment: or specify them when you "run" it ie "run hello world"

Comment: That `argv[0]` is `/home/pi/new/a.out` is because you did not rename your program to `echo`. Although I must confess that K&R don't mention the path, or maybe that got added later in the definition of `argv[0]`.

Comment: You cannot access `argv[2]` and beyond if `argc` is 1.  You cannot access `argv[3]`  if `argc` is 2, etc. Any such value you obtain from the debugger is meaningless.

Comment: Your first mistake is not checking argc. That would have told you there is only 1 string and no actual arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying argv in the loop:

```
while (--argc>0)
        printf("%s%s",*++argv,(argc>1)?" ":"");
```

so that observing it after don't give you what you think! You are overflowing the array and access the environment array...

Either observe argv before the loop or at least store its original value somewhere to observe it after... As you didn't tell us what was the exact (all commands!) gdb session you made, we cannot help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Snippet 1) `0x7efff85a` is a pointer to the string `"/home/pi/new/a.out"` for this instance of the program.

Snippet 2) `0x7efffe5a` is a pointer to the string `"_=/usr/bin/gdb"` for this particular instance, but you shouldn't rely on `argv[argc+1]` onwards pointing to anything in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the full definition of `main` is:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
```

This means that following the last `argv[]` follow the environment variables.

Comment: It isn't actually guaranteed to mean that. But you are right that the internal convention on unix is that the piece of memory envp points to immediately follows the memory argv points to.